# How to access a variable from controller in my case

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, controller

I have a simple VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityExt">  
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function initialize(){
     alert('Value ' + '{!abc}');
 }
 </script> 
 <apex:form > 
          <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" action="{!search}" value="Search" oncomplete="initialize();"/>
  </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

Controller class:

```
public class OpportunityExt {

    public void search() {
        abc='hello';
    }

    public string abc{get;set;}
    public OpportunityExt() {
       // can set the abc value only here.

    }

}
```

**The problem:**

I am trying to set the value of `abc` string in `search()` method and access the value in the javascript method `initialize()` . But this does not work. I get an empty value in the alert message. However when I set the abc value in Constructor I get a the value in alert message.

How can set the value of a controller variable and access it in javascript `intialize()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `{!abc}` in your javascript is set when the page is first loaded, after running the constructor. To get the updated value, you'll need to cause a  a rerender of your javascript, putting the correct value on your page.

For example:

```
<apex:page controller="OpportunityExt">  

 <apex:form>

    <apex:outputPanel id="Something">
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            function initialize() {
                alert('Value ' + '{!abc}');
            }
        </script> 
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <apex:commandButton id="saveBtn" rerender="Something" action="{!search}" value="Search" oncomplete="initialize();"/>

  </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

---

The `oncomplete="initialize();"` is pure javascript, and only happens when the buttons `action` has completed. The `reRender` matters because it refreshes the `outputPanel`.  When a component is rerendered, it will update any merge fields in the component (`{!abc}` in this case), and will use the current value of that variable on the server side.

`{!abc}`'s value is set by the action, then the value is reset on the page, then the `oncomplete="initialize();"` runs, using the newly set value in the javascript. The order of operations here is very important.

Comment: Great. Wanted to understand that why do we need to reRender when we are already calling the function on Oncomplete. So is it like we are calling the Initialize() method twice?

Comment: The function is only called once, after the action and the rerender have completed. See my edit to the answer.

Comment: Well explained.!